# Firebase realtime database tracking changes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to track all changes in the database in onStart method of an activity, but the following code works only when the first "row" of the firebase tree is changed:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(child.getKey() + " : " + child.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

I tried to track each child separately by creating one listener for each child, but it worked only for the first child as well. How can I track updates for all of them? Thank you.

Update. There are jsut 3 childs in the tree:

[image]

I need to be able to see when any of them are updated.

Comment: It would be helful if you posted the Firebase structure (the specific part you want to listen) + how you created mDatabase. Also check the [latest documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#attach_an_event_listener).

Comment: @user2819864 I just wrote mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();. I edited the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using addChildEventListener:

```
getDatabase().getReference().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

hey have you try using child_added event listener?

Child events

Child events are triggered in response to specific operations that happen to the children of a node from an operation such as a new child added through the push() method or a child being updated through the updateChildren() method. Each of these together can be useful for listening to changes to a specific node in a database.